# R optim function - Setting constraints for individual parameters

Tags: r, optimization

I am looking to minimize a function using `optim` as follows:

```
yield <- function(data, par) {
  with(data, par[1] + (par[2] + par[3]/par[4])*(1-exp(-par[4]*maturity))/(par[4]*maturity) - (par[3]*exp(-par[4]*maturity)/par[4]))
}
min.RSS <- function(data, par) {
  sum((data$price - 100*exp(-data$maturity*yield(data, par)))^2)
}
result <- optim(par = theta, min.RSS, data = data))
```

The parameters `par[1]` and `par[4]` must be non-negative, while the other two are unconstrained. Is it possible to include these constraints in the `optim` function?

Thanks

Comment: If you passed logged versions of those parameters and then exp() them on return you would have impose that constraint. The help page for `optim` links to  `?constrOptim`

Comment: And by the way, we need DATA. Give us DATA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to make @BondedDust's suggestion abundantly clear:

```
yield <- function(data, par) {
  with(data, par[1] + (par[2] + par[3]/par[4])*(1-exp(-par[4]*maturity))/(par[4]*maturity) - (par[3]*exp(-par[4]*maturity)/par[4]))
}

# the function being optimized
min.RSS <- function(data, par) {

  # EXPONENETIATE PARAMTERS 1 AND 4 TO MAKE THEM POSITIVE.
  par[1] <- exp(par[1])
  par[4] <- exp(par[4])

  sum((data$price - 100*exp(-data$maturity*yield(data, par)))^2)

}


PAR <- theta

# LOG TRANSFRORM THE INITIAL VALUES FOR PARAMTERS 1 AND 4
PAR[1] <- log(PAR[1])
PAR[4] <- log(PAR[4])

# CALL optim()
result <- optim(par = PAR,
                min.RSS,
                data = data))


# THE BEST SET OF PARAMETERS
par <- result$par
# again, exponenetiate paramters 1 and 4 to make them positive.
par[1] <- log(par[1])
par[4] <- log(par[4])
```